# VMware Player Hangs for VM and cannot delete

Tags: vmware-player

I'm trying to learn VMware Player and I created a couple VMs successfully. One of the VMs somehow got into some weird state where I can't do anything with it. It won't run or anything. Ok, so I now I just want to delete it. However when I select "Delete VM from disk" option, VMware Player just hangs. Then when I try to exit Player it says the VM is busy...

Any idea how I can get just delete the garbage VM?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Version 6, now. Win 7 HPE [or any Win] is where you delete any virtuals. If you are too far ahead to do a System Restore, try re-installing the latest VM Player. It's a simple Setup, but when it goes wrong, it's havoc. Your Guest won't be affected.